# Condition.signal() won't awake randomly

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I've got the following code, where zero(), even(), odd() are supposed to be called by three individual threads, and called in such a sequence: zero() - odd() - zero() - even() until n is reached.

```
public class ZeroEvenOdd {

  private int n;

  private volatile int start = 1;

  private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  private Condition zero = lock.newCondition();
  private Condition even = lock.newCondition();
  private Condition odd = lock.newCondition();

  public ZeroEvenOdd(int n) {
    this.n = n;
  }

  // printNumber.accept(x) outputs "x", where x is an integer.
  public void zero(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      while (start <= n) {
        printNumber.accept(0);
        if (start % 2 == 0) {
          even.signal();
        } else {
          odd.signal();
        }
        zero.await();
        System.out.println("zero awake");
      }
      odd.signal();
      even.signal();
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public void even(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      while (start <= n) {
        if (start % 2 != 0) {
          even.await();
        } else {
          printNumber.accept(start++);
          zero.signal();
        }
      }
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public void odd(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      while (start <= n) {
        if (start % 2 == 0) {
          odd.await();
        } else {
          printNumber.accept(start++);
          zero.signal();
        }
      }
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the testcase:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntConsumer consumer = new IntConsumer() {
      @Override
      public void accept(int value) {
        System.out.println(value);
      }
    };
    ZeroEvenOdd zeroEvenOdd = new ZeroEvenOdd(4);

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        zeroEvenOdd.zero(consumer);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    });
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        zeroEvenOdd.odd(consumer);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    });
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        zeroEvenOdd.even(consumer);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    });
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();
  }
```

Idealy when n=5, it is supposed to print 0102030405, however, when running the testcase, sometimes I get 012030405 printed, which means when start==2, the condition zero was not awaken, but instead condition even was awake. How did this happen? If i changed the code a little bit by adding a seperate flag then the problem is solved:

```
public class ZeroEvenOdd {
  private int n;

  private volatile int start = 1;

  private volatile int who;
  private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  private Condition zero = lock.newCondition();
  private Condition even = lock.newCondition();
  private Condition odd = lock.newCondition();

  public ZeroEvenOdd(int n) {
    this.n = n;
  }

  // printNumber.accept(x) outputs "x", where x is an integer.
  public void zero(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      while (start <= n) {
        if (who!=0) {
          zero.await();
        }
        printNumber.accept(0);
        if (start % 2 == 0) {
          who=2;
          even.signal();
        } else {
          who=1;
          odd.signal();
        }
        zero.await();
      }
      odd.signal();
      even.signal();
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

   public void even(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      while (start <= n) {
        if (who!=2) {
          even.await();
        } else {
          printNumber.accept(start++);
          who=0;
          zero.signal();
        }
      }
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public void odd(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      while (start <= n) {
        if (who!=1) {
          odd.await();
        } else {
          printNumber.accept(start++);
          who=0;
          zero.signal();
        }
      }
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

I just can't see the mechanics underlying this phenomenon. Please help me to clarify this problem.

Comment: Just because you call `Thread.start` in a particular order does not guarantee the threads execute in that order. So regardless that you did this - `thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();` thread3 could execute first, then thread2, then thread1 for example. You are merely telling the scheduler that they are ready to execute, not dictating the order of execution.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I can see that the first class is problematic because it didn't consider the possibility that `zero()` gets executed after the other two threads. But when n gets to 2, it means that the Condition zero must be awaiting and has been signaled inside the method `odd()`, how did it skip printing 0 and get to method `even()`?

Comment: From [ReentrantLock Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) "...this lock does not guarantee any particular access order"

Comment: You're welcome, there are definitely a lot of subtleties to consider with concurrency. It's a tricky topic to be sure. Great job providing an MCVE with your question,  a lot of new users don't do that :)